# Displaying all country names when using ggmap with a large zoom-factor

Tags: r, format, ggmap, country

I tried to plot a map using `ggmap`'s `get_googlemap` function and to format the country names.
The download gives me a map where not all country names are displayed by default, probably due to the zoom factor. Since I scale it slightly down after that, there would be enough space for additional country names. What is more, I also want to do a little formatting and get rid of the white background behind the country names.
Unfortunately, google's formatting syntax for its maps does not seem to work the way it should or I might be using it the wrong way.

Please note that I do not need to rely on google maps, openstreet maps would actually be preferred. Nonetheless, I cannot use them at the moment, since downloading a map with the get_map function always gives me an error (could be a server-issue) when specifying `source = "osm"`.

So what I tried is this:

```
library(ggmap)

map <- get_googlemap(center = "Europe", zoom = 3, 
                     style = paste(         #selecting all countries
                                   "feature:administrative.country|",
                                            #trying to make all country names visible
                                   "element:labels.text|visibility:all|",
                                            #trying to reduce the white background to 0
                                   "element:geometry.fill|weight:0|",
                                            #trying to play around with text size
                                   "element:labels.text|weight:20|"
                                   sep = ""),
                     filename = "MAP", language = "en-EN")
ggmap(map) #displaying the raw map

#Scaling down the map and removing unnecessary information
ggmap(map)+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-25, 57), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(25, 70), expand = c(0, 0))+
  theme(axis.title.x    = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y    = element_blank(),
        axis.line       = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks      = element_blank(),
        axis.text       = element_blank(),
        plot.title      = element_blank(),
        plot.background = element_blank())
```

What I get looks like this: [image: sample map]

As you can see, not all country names are displayed and the formatting did not work the way it should.
Of course, I could use the `annotate` function and write the missing country names manually (see example below), but is there a more comfortable way during the download (if possible openstreetmap preferred)?

The worst case would be having to add the missing names by hand as follows:

```
ggmap(map)+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-25, 57), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(25, 70), expand = c(0, 0))+
  theme(axis.title.x    = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y    = element_blank(),
        axis.line       = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks      = element_blank(),
        axis.text       = element_blank(),
        plot.title      = element_blank(),
        plot.background = element_blank()) +
  annotate("text", x = 20.21484375, y = 40.245991504199026, 
           label =  "Albania", 
           size = 4, color = "black", fontface = "plain")
```

This would work, but there is still a large visible difference between the text formats. In a second step, I am going to add numbers to each country with the `annotate` function, so adjusting the text size will be necessary.

This is what I get when adding the country names manually: [image: sample map with annotation]

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: When replacing the google-syntax by

```
paste("feature:administrative.country|",
      "element:labels|visibility:off",
      sep = "")
```

it is at least possible to switch off all country names and to add all of them manually, which makes formatting easier.

Comment: Not really related to your question, but `ggmap` throws an error when you specify `source = osm`, because it either 1) uses the Google Maps API to lookup the location and you don't have a valid API key or 2) you supplied a centroid `lon`/`lat` instead of `minlon`, `minlat`, `maxlon`, and `maxlat`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I remember that I played around with osm a bit in the past also ending up with errors related to the size of the map-file due to the details of os-maps. For the sake of simplicity I kept going with google-maps. But I'd appreciate it if you could give me a short code snippet for osm-download in order to test if I get it to work.